# Click Button on the bottom of the page

Tags: imacros

I'm having a hard time programming iMacros to click on one single button..
Please see the following page: http://iconosquare.com/viewer.php#/user/25025320/

I want iMacro to click the bottom button that says "MORE"
What "code" can I use to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this code?

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:more
```

Comment: This is the code I used few times and it worked. I don't understand your comment.